# BookshelfJS belongsToMany doesn't return duplicates

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, bookshelf.js

I have two tables that are have the relationship `belongsToMany`. The pivot table also contains a column called `state` that could have 3 different values. Say my tables are `Table1` and `Table2`.

There can be multiple entries for the same `Table1-Table2` relation with different `states`.

I want to get all the pivot entries for `Table1` including any multiple entries for the same `Table2`.

Unfortunately, the code

```
return this.belongsToMany(Table2, 'pivot_table1_table2').withPivot(['state'])
```

only returns the first entry for each `Table2`.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Same here, I don't understand why it's a default and not an opt-in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how bookshelf works! It's part of the feature: remove the dupes. I found a workaround; explicitly select an attribute from the junction table that's unique. If you don't have one, create a model for the junction table. That's sadly the only solution then.

UPDATE:

Perhaps something like that. routes.code is unique in my case and it is part of the junction table. If this won't do the trick, create a model for the junction table and you're set (this is probably more preferred).

```
new Station().where({
    id: req.params.id
}).fetch({
    withRelated: [{
        'routes': function(qb) {
            qb.select('routes.id', 'routes.code');
        }
    }]
}).then(function(result) {
    res.json(result.toJSON());
});
```

Comment: I have a `creation_date` column that would totally be unique, so I could use that. But how do I go about it? Could you provide an example code?

Comment: Quick question: in the above statement, you are the query inside `withRealted` is for the `routes` table. So you are actually referring to another `route`. I literally have the same entry that will need to show up in the pivot table. So I don't understand how it would help me here. I'd need to do something on the pivot table, not the `routes` table.